# Can't connect to AWS instance using Apache Server VirtualHost

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4

I have an Ubuntu Instance on AWS.  I have a small web page running on an Apache 2.4 server.  I can access the web page from my own computer and devices off of my network when I use the Public DNS or Public IP of the AWS instance.  However, I can't access it from the ServerName address that is defined in my virtual host.

Here is my gci.conf:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /html/website
        ServerName gci.example.com
    </VirtualHost>
```

Everything seems to be set up correctly, based on the output of apache2ctl:

```
  VirtualHost configuration:
  *:80                   gci.example.com 
  (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gci.conf:1)
  ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
  Main DocumentRoot: "/html/website"
```

When I try to access the web page from 'gci.example.com' I get an error that the "IP can not be found"

I have been stuck on this for hours and have looked extensively at the documentation and other online resources.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you give the *exact* wording of the error you receive? And, ideally, the non-censored domain/subdomain you're working with? It sounds like you may just not have pointed `gci.example.com` at the right IP address.

Comment: @ceejayoz The exact error I am getting from Google Chrome "is This site can’t be reached gci.example.com’s server IP address could not be found.
Go to http://example.com/
Search Google for gci example
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" And sorry, what do you mean by the non-censored domain/subdomain?  Are you looking for the Public DNS?

Comment: No, I'm looking for the `ServerName` you're using. `gci.example.com`, but obviously you don't control example.com so I'm looking for the *actual* domain you're using. Did you set up DNS records for it?

Comment: @ceejayoz No I did not.  I followed these steps: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-apache#3 and all they was add a ServerName (gci.example.com) to the  gci.conf

Comment: Well, that's your problem, then. You need a DNS record in place.

Comment: Ah okay.  Interesting how the tutorial skipped that step. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, I just paged through the tutorial and I'm *baffled* that they didn't talk about that requirement at all. Sorry, you ran into a bad tutorial.

Comment: It happens.  I've been trying to go through the official Apache docs and they don't do a great job either at outlining all the steps.  Thanks again.